# clang error when installing "dependencies" package with pip

Tags: python, clang, pip, statsmodels

I'm trying to test [this](http://www.datarobot.com/blog/multiple-regression-using-statsmodels/) implementation of multiple linear regression in python. It requires "statsmodels.api", however when I try to do "import statsmodels.api", I get the error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/api.py in <module>()
     16 from .duration.hazard_regression import PHReg
     17 from .nonparametric import api as nonparametric
---> 18 from . import distributions
     19 from .__init__ import test
     20 from . import version

ImportError: cannot import name distributions
```

so I tried to install the "distributions" package with pip:

```
$ pip install distributions
```

however, it fails with a clang error:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/distributions/lp/special.o -ldistributions_shared -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/distributions/lp/special.so
ld: library not found for -ldistributions_shared
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried my best to figure out what -ldistrbutions_shared is, but I can't seem to figure it out.

No luck when I tried updating xcode. All my internet searching hasn't been able to help me resolve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

BTW, I'm running OSX 10.10.5 and using Python 2.7

Comment: The problem here is that your *statsmodels* installation is borked. The *distributions* pypi package is not related to *statsmodels*. Probably it's not OSX compatible. You may want to try reinstalling *statsmodels* or switching to a binary distribution like *anaconda*

Comment: Hi cel, thanks for your comment. I've never heard of anaconda, it sounds like a great alternative to installing packages as needed. I assume there is nothing special about anaconda, except that it is a 'guaranteed' way to install python with a number of packages? I.e., if I wanted to add additional packaged later, I could just use pip?

Comment: The `anaconda` distribution gives you `conda`, which is basically a new package manager that provides binary packages for the most common scientific packages. Of course you can choose to install some packages with `conda` and some with `pip`.

Comment: So, in other words, that anaconda don't want none unless it's got .bins, huh